# Bind List to GridviewComboboxcolumn in telerik radgrindview (winform)

Tags: telerik, bind, radgridview

I have a generic List like

```
List<return> returnlist 

class return
{
  public string returnid {get; set;
  ...
  public List<string> Vouchernumbers
}
```

I bind the returnlist to the telerik radgridview.

How can i bind the voucherlist to the GridviewComboboxcolumn for each row ?

I have bind the voucherlist to the combobox after radgridview_complete_binding.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create the grid with columns and data
2. You need to add the combobox column, initialize it.. Please check you need to have a dataeditor in here
3. Assign the string to datasource

   comboColumn.DataSource = new String[] { "Test1", "Test2"};
4. You can bind the collections too:

   ```
   Binding list BindingList<ComboBoxDataSourceObject>  list                                      = new BindingList<ComboBoxDataSourceObject>();
   ComboBoxDataSourceObject object1 = new ComboBoxDataSourceObject();
   object1.Id = 1;
   object1.MyString = "Test 1";
   list.Add(object1);

   ComboBoxDataSourceObject object2 = new ComboBoxDataSourceObject();
   object2.Id = 2;
   object2.MyString = "Test 2";
   list.Add(object2);

   colboCol2.DataSource = list;
   radGridView1.Columns.Add(colboCol2);
   ```

Comment: [Please check the explanation from telerik](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-columns-gridviewcomboboxcolumn.html)

Comment: This is not the problem. I want to bind the voucherlist for each row in the radgrid. I have bind the voucherlist after radgrid_binding_complete, but the column shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

create radcombobox and set datasource and add it to rad grid

eg :

```
GridViewComboBoxColumn col = new GridViewComboBoxColumn();
col.DataSource = DAL.ActiveDb.GetList<SalesRep>().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.RepName).Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, x.RepName });
col.DropDownStyle = RadDropDownStyle.DropDown;
col.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;

col.DisplayMember = "RepName";
col.ValueMember = "Id";
col.FieldName = "RepId";
col.HeaderText = "Rep Name";
col.Width = 200;
//var t = gridColInfo.Where(x => x.ColumnName.ToLower() == "repid").FirstOrDefault();
//if (t != null)
//{
//    col.Width = t.ColumnWidth;
//}
this.radGridBillwiseOpening.Columns.Add(col);
```

Comment: *why* does this help? Could you explain your answer?